# Analyzing customers in python

Tags: python

I want to find out the total expenses of a customer and total expense made on a date from the 2 dictionaries

```
def analysis(file: str, customer: str, date: str) -> (float, float):
    try:
        with open(file, 'r') as filehand:
            for row in filehand:
                print(row)r]
            else:
                return "Name not found"
            if date in dates:
                date_expense = dates[date]
            else:
                return "Date not found"
    except:
        return "File not found"
```

Comment: The format `return print("message")` Is not valid. You probably wanted `raise Exception("message")`

Comment: @flakes thanks! i fixed that part, although im still not yileding the correct results overall.

Comment: Note that "csv" is not an "external library" and is part of the standard library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have bad news. You made almost every possible mistake there :)

First, it is considered bad practice to use just `except:` statement, you should check for specific exception types, so you don't miss the mistakes in your code. You could read about exception types in python [there](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html).

Bad:

```py
except:     # catches all possible errors
    return "File not found"
```

Good:

```py
except OSError:     # catches only OS errors such as "file not found", "disk full", etc.
    return "File not found"
```

In particular, because you used `except:`, you didn't catch that mistake:

```py
return customer_name.get(name, "Name not found")
```

You use `customer` argument for customer name and not the `name` and it cause the exception which wasn't caught.

Then, there is a problem with reading the file:

```py
customer_name = {rows[0]:rows[2] for rows in filehand}
dates = {rows[3]:rows[2] for rows in filehand}
```

`rows[N]` gives you the Nth symbol from the line in the file, something you don't want to. So, the results are:

```py
>>> customer_name
{'A': 'i', 'S': 's', 'N': 'c', 'M': 'c'}
>>> dates
{}
```

`dates` is just `{}` because you have already read the whole file to build the `customer_name` dict.

To create the data rows you should split the string first and then make the dictionaries. Like that (@SmellyCat also mentioned that in his answer):

```py
rows = [row.strip().split(',') for row in filehand]
customer_name = {row[0]: row[2] for row in rows}
dates = {row[3]: row[2] for row in rows}
```

Anyway, the use of dict comprehensions there is a bad idea cause it doesn't give what you expected:

```py
>>> customer_name
{'Alice White': '600', 'Susan Green': '500', 'Nick Hanes': '500', 'Michael Jones': '155'}
```

As you can see, only the last data entry is saved for each customer. But we want to get the sums. So we need a different approach. For example, we could use the `defaultdict` from `collections` module to aggregate values for each customer/date. Read more about defaultdict [there](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```py
customer_name = defaultdict(float)    # set the 0.0 value when the key is missed
dates = defaultdict(float)
for row in rows:
    name = row[0]
    amount = float(row[2])    # need to convert amount to float type
    sale_date = row[3]
    customer_name[name] += amount
    dates[sale_date] += amount
```

(Edited) You can implement it also just with plain `dict`. If so, you should add `try/except` block to catch possible key errors:

```py
customer_name = {}
dates = {}
for row in rows:
    name = row[0]
    amount = float(row[2])
    sale_date = row[3]
    try:
        customer_name[name] += amount
    except KeyError:     # If name is not present in the dictionary
        customer_name[name] = amount
    try:
        dates[sale_date] += amount
    except KeyError:     # If date is not present in the dictionary
        dates[sale_date] = amount
```

OK, we have our dictionaries. Let's check if the `customer` or `date` are in them. The lines below don't work because `some_dict.items()` gives you a list of `(key, value)` tuples, so you obviously won't find any `str` in that because `str` is not a `tuple`. It will always give you `False`. In this case you could just search the key in the dict itself as it searches in the keys by default.

Don't work

```py
if customer in customer_name.items():
if date in dates.items():
```

Works well:

```py
if customer in customer_name:
if date in dates:
```

So, we find our `customer`/`date` in our dictionaries. But we run into another problem. These lines gives us the sum of all expenses and not for a particular `customer`/`date`.

```py
customer_expense = sum(list(customer_name.values()))
date_expense = sum(list(dates.values()))
```

To get the expense for particular `customer` we can just use `customer_name[customer]` and similarly for `date`. And in the `else` block we just return the needed string.

Instead of this:

```py
if customer in customer_name.items():
    customer_expense = sum(list(customer_name.values()))
else:
    return customer_name.get(name, "Name not found")
```

Do this:

```py
if customer in customer_name:
    customer_expense = customer_name[customer]
else:
    return "Name not found"
```

The full code looks like this (implementation using plain `dict`):

```py
def customer_analysis(filename: str, customer: str, date: str) -> (float, float):
    try:
        with open(filename, 'r') as filehand:
            rows = [row.strip().split(',') for row in filehand]
            customer_name = {}
            dates = {}
            for row in rows:
                name = row[0]
                amount = float(row[2])
                sale_date = row[3]
                customer_name.setdefault(name, 0.0)
                customer_name[name] += amount
                dates.setdefault(sale_date, 0.0)
                dates[sale_date] += amount

        if customer in customer_name:
            customer_expense = customer_name[customer]
        else:
            return "Name not found"
        if date in dates:
            date_expense = dates[date]
        else:
            return "Date not found"
    except OSError:
        return "File not found"

    return customer_expense, date_expense
```

And for your inputs returns as expected:

```py
>>> customer_analysis(filename=filename, customer='Alice White', date='2023-09-05')
(615.0, 170.0)
```

If the name is not found in the file:

```py
>>> customer_analysis(filename=filename, customer='Somebody', date='2023-09-05')
Name not found
```

If the date is not found:

```py
>>> customer_analysis(filename=filename, customer='Alice White', date='1492-10-13')
Date not found
```

Comment: hello! thanks! is there a way to do this without importing the defaultdict ?

Comment: Of course! You could use `try/except` block to imitate defaultdict behavior. I updated the answer adding this implementation

Comment: Can you clarify what code did you test? The one that is in the question now or something else? "File not found" will show in my variant of code only if the the function gets the wrong filename, so it's very strange to see this result so often

Comment: The code that is in your question right now will give an incorrect output if there are several entries for one person or date.

Comment: There is no need in using `.get()` method. You could just modify the code according to my example code in the end of my answer. I don't see any issues with this code

Comment: Ah that strange. I have no problem running this on my computer. I update the example code in my answer again excluding some `try/except` statements. Maybe it will help

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you need to return only "No name found" when there is no name in the file and not the ('No name found', 170) `tuple`?

Comment: i must return "No name found" when the name that is given is not in the data file!

Comment: your updated code did work! thanks!

Comment: Wow great! I surprised that such change makes a difference :) All autograder questions correct?

Comment: yes! there were 3 tests and it passed all 3

Comment: Cool! Could you mark my answer as accepted then? So, this question will be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to split each row?

```
rows = [row.split(',') for row in filehand]
customer_name = {row[0]:int(row[2]) for row in rows}
dates = {row[3]:int(row[2]) for row in rows}
```

Without splitting each input line, the [] operator is extracting individual elements from the strings.

Comment: this actually helped a ton thank you! I am still getting one incorrect in the autograder. i updated my code in the OG, do you have any suggestions?